# Python3をダウンロードしたのに古いバージョンが起動してしまう

Tags: python, macos

Python3をダウンロードしたのですが、ターミナルでバージョンを確認すると

```
python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

となり、Python2のままになっています。
ちなみに、対話モードを起動すると

```
python3
Python 3.9.7 (v3.9.7:1016ef3790, Aug 30 2021, 16:39:15) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

このように以前ダウンロードしたPython3が起動します。
デフォルトでPython3を起動させる方法を教えてください。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[Mac OS での Python アップデート（備忘録）](https://www.comp.tmu.ac.jp/s-yokoyama/misc/pythonmac.html), [MacのPythonを2系から3系にアップデートする](https://qiita.com/Ajyarimochi/items/ff40e57d082dd171e761), [Python3 をアップデートする方法(macOS - Homebrew)](https://www.curict.com/item/86/8696368.html)

Comment: python.org から .pkg ファイルをダウンロードしたのであれば，通常のインストール先は `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.??/bin` です。ここの検索順位を `echo $PATH` で確認し，含まれていないまたは低順位であればシェルの設定ファイルで変更ください。

Comment: 単にダウンロードしただけではインストールされないはずです。ダウンロードやインストールであなたが実際に行った手順についても詳しく記載があると、回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

（情報の補足がないようなので、一般論で回答します）

macOS では、システム標準でインストールされた `python` の参照先を `python3` に変える方法はないようです。

ですので、次のような方法しかなさそうです。

- シェルで `python` 実行時に `python3` を参照するようにする

  - `.bashrc` 、 `.zshrc` などで、 `alias python=python3` を設定する
- `pyenv` で参照先を変更する

  - `pyenv install 3.11` してから `pyenv shell 3.11` など

参考： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x

// ちなみに、Linux系ディストリビューションでは、 `python` のように複数のバージョンがインストールされるコマンドの参照先を切り替える `update-alternavite` というツールが存在し、 `pyenv` やシェルの設定変更を行わずに `python` が `python3` （や `python2`）を指すように切り替えることができたりします。